# Store Uploaded File in MongoDB GridFS Using mgodb-go-driver without Saving to Memory

Tags: mongodb, file, go

I am using below Go MongoDB plugin 
[MongoDB-GO-Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/tree/master/mongo/gridfs) to store ymal file data.

I am using `gridfs.NewBucket()` method.

```
 func (s *FS) CreateFilewithBytes(data []byte, filename string) error {

    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(data)
    chunksize, _ := binary.ReadVarint(buf)
    _, err := gridfs.NewBucket(db,
        options.GridFSBucket().
            SetName(filename).
            SetChunkSizeBytes(int32(chunksize))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    } 
}
```

Please help me out how to store file and read file data.

Comment: any error messages? Any more details on the failure?

Comment: Question is here how to convert byte array in chunksize